I cant instaall ubuntu, please help
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping /dev/nvme0n1p2 attempt 1/4
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['wipefs', '--all', '--force', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         /dev/nvme0n1p2: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000438 (ext4): 53 ef
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping 1M on /dev/nvme0n1p2 at offsets [0, -1048576]
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         devname '/dev/nvme0n1p2' had holders: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device holders with exclusive access: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device mounts: ['/dev/nvme0n1p2 /media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0']
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['fuser', '--verbose', '--mount', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Possible users of /dev/nvme0n1p2:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         {'kernel': ['/dev/nvme0n1p2:', 'root', 'mount', '/media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc']}
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         devname '/dev/nvme0n1p2' had holders: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device holders with exclusive access: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device mounts: ['/dev/nvme0n1p2 /media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0']
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['fuser', '--verbose', '--mount', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Possible users of /dev/nvme0n1p2:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         {'kernel': ['/dev/nvme0n1p2:', 'root', 'mount', '/media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc']}
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping device '/dev/nvme0n1p2' failed on attempt 1/4.  sleeping 1s before retry
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping /dev/nvme0n1p2 attempt 2/4
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['wipefs', '--all', '--force', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping 1M on /dev/nvme0n1p2 at offsets [0, -1048576]
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         devname '/dev/nvme0n1p2' had holders: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device holders with exclusive access: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device mounts: ['/dev/nvme0n1p2 /media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0']
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['fuser', '--verbose', '--mount', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Possible users of /dev/nvme0n1p2:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         {'kernel': ['/dev/nvme0n1p2:', 'root', 'mount', '/media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc']}
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         devname '/dev/nvme0n1p2' had holders: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device holders with exclusive access: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device mounts: ['/dev/nvme0n1p2 /media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0']
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['fuser', '--verbose', '--mount', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Possible users of /dev/nvme0n1p2:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         {'kernel': ['/dev/nvme0n1p2:', 'root', 'mount', '/media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc']}
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping device '/dev/nvme0n1p2' failed on attempt 2/4.  sleeping 3s before retry
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping /dev/nvme0n1p2 attempt 3/4
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['wipefs', '--all', '--force', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping 1M on /dev/nvme0n1p2 at offsets [0, -1048576]
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         devname '/dev/nvme0n1p2' had holders: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device holders with exclusive access: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device mounts: ['/dev/nvme0n1p2 /media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0']
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['fuser', '--verbose', '--mount', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Possible users of /dev/nvme0n1p2:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         {'kernel': ['/dev/nvme0n1p2:', 'root', 'mount', '/media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc']}
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         devname '/dev/nvme0n1p2' had holders: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device holders with exclusive access: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device mounts: ['/dev/nvme0n1p2 /media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0']
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['fuser', '--verbose', '--mount', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Possible users of /dev/nvme0n1p2:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         {'kernel': ['/dev/nvme0n1p2:', 'root', 'mount', '/media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc']}
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping device '/dev/nvme0n1p2' failed on attempt 3/4.  sleeping 5s before retry
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping /dev/nvme0n1p2 attempt 4/4
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['wipefs', '--all', '--force', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         wiping 1M on /dev/nvme0n1p2 at offsets [0, -1048576]
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         devname '/dev/nvme0n1p2' had holders: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device holders with exclusive access: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device mounts: ['/dev/nvme0n1p2 /media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0']
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['fuser', '--verbose', '--mount', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Possible users of /dev/nvme0n1p2:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         {'kernel': ['/dev/nvme0n1p2:', 'root', 'mount', '/media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc']}
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Failed to exclusively open path: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         devname '/dev/nvme0n1p2' had holders: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device holders with exclusive access: []
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Device mounts: ['/dev/nvme0n1p2 /media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0']
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Running command ['fuser', '--verbose', '--mount', '/dev/nvme0n1p2'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=True)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Possible users of /dev/nvme0n1p2:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         {'kernel': ['/dev/nvme0n1p2:', 'root', 'mount', '/media/ubuntu/d38dd3fc-58ca-46ab-87a3-6e7300b7cebc']}
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta/clear-holders: FAIL: removing previous storage devices
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         TIMED BLOCK_META: 19.631
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         finish: cmd-install/stage-partitioning/builtin/cmd-block-meta: FAIL: curtin command block-meta
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/block/__init__.py", line 1173, in exclusive_open
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             fd = os.open(path, flags)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/nvme0n1p2'
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/main.py", line 202, in main
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             ret = args.func(args)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/log.py", line 97, in wrapper
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             return log_time("TIMED %s: " % msg, func, *args, **kwargs)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/log.py", line 79, in log_time
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             return func(*args, **kwargs)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 118, in block_meta
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             meta_clear(devices, state.get('report_stack_prefix', ''))
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/commands/block_meta.py", line 2213, in meta_clear
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             clear_holders.clear_holders(devices)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/block/clear_holders.py", line 638, in clear_holders
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             shutdown_function(dev_info['device'])
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/block/clear_holders.py", line 311, in wipe_superblock
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             _wipe_superblock(blockdev)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/block/clear_holders.py", line 344, in _wipe_superblock
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             block.wipe_volume(blockdev, mode='superblock', exclusive=exclusive)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/block/__init__.py", line 1351, in wipe_volume
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             quick_zero(path, partitions=False, exclusive=exclusive)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/block/__init__.py", line 1264, in quick_zero
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             util.not_exclusive_retry(
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/util.py", line 1422, in not_exclusive_retry
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             return fun(*args, **kwargs)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_event.6322[6322]:   curtin command install
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/block/__init__.py", line 1286, in zero_file_at_offsets
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             with exclusive_open(path, exclusive=exclusive) as fp:
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             return next(self.gen)
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:           File "/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/237/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curtin/block/__init__.py", line 1195, in exclusive_open
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:             raise NotExclusiveError from exc
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         curtin.util.NotExclusiveError
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]:         
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_log.6322[11445]: Stderr: ''
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_event.6322[6322]:  executing curtin install partitioning step
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_event.6322[6322]: installing system
Sep 02 11:23:09 ubuntu subiquity_event.6322[6322]: 

